# Do I need to check isDisposed() before calling dispose()?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm learning RxJava and I noticed a lot of the sample code does a `isDisposed()` check before calling `dispose()`. I did not notice any issues when I called `dispose()` on an already disposed `Disposable`.

So my question is, do I need the `isDisposed()` check? Are there situations where I should check `isDisposed()` before disposing? What are the pros and cons on doing the check first?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It makes little sense to call `isDisposed`. `dispose` implementations already do that for you and make sure repeated calls are no-ops or have no detectable effect.

Unfortunately, somebody in the early days of RxJava started writing examples with it and now everybody keeps copying that pattern.

It makes a little more sense to check `isDisposed` before calling `onNext` for example but you don't get to do that very often outside `Observable.create()`.

Comment: When does it make sense to check `isDisposed` before calling `onNext` and why? -- I've found code which calls it every time when using `Single.create` etc. , is it possible to abuse a single in any way to make it be disposed and then try to make it emit something? What happens if you don't check for `isDisposed` in these cases?

Comment: @SimonForsberg Depends on what the sequence does in your found code. Maybe they have a create-dispose race and want to avoid undeliverable exceptions by doing eager isDispose checks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. If you check for example the implementation of `CompositeDisposable`,

```
     @Override
        public void dispose() {
            if (disposed) {
                return;
            }
    ...rest of method body
    @Override
        public boolean isDisposed() {
            return disposed;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

dispose is basically for closing the stream of your subscription. you're checking isdisposed() will tell you if the existing stream is active. if any relevant data passing through that stream it will be cut.

Ofcors, you can call dispose anytime.

Answer (score -1):

what about safeDispose?

```
fun Disposable?.safeDispose() {
    if (this?.isDisposed == false) {
        dispose()
    }
}
```